# Angular, Type 'Promise<void | Task>'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have this error when compiling a project.
error terminal:

```
ERROR in src/app/services/task.ts(44,5): error TS2322: Type 
'Promise<void | Task>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Task>'.
Type 'void | Task' is not assignable to type 'Task'.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Task'.
```

---

Here is the code in which the error is knocked out.

```
26 loadTasks(): Promise<Task[]> {
27 const url = `${this.tasksUrl}?access_token=${localStorage.getItem('token')}`;
28 return this.http.get(url)
29   .toPromise()
30 .then(res => res.json() as Task[])
31  .catch(error => this.handleError(error, 'Could not load tasks!'));
32 }
33 getTask(id: number): Promise<Task> {
34 const url = `${this.tasksUrl}/${id}?access_token=${localStorage.getItem('token')}`;
35 return this.http.get(url)
36  .toPromise()
37  .then(res => res.json() as Task)
38  .catch(error => this.handleError(error, 'Could not load task!'));
39 }
40 create(task): Promise<Task> {
41 task['due_date'] = task['due_date']['formatted'];
42 let body = JSON.stringify({task: task});
43 const url = `${this.tasksUrl}?access_token=${localStorage.getItem('token')}`;
44 return this.http.post(url, body, { headers: this.headers })
45  .toPromise()
46  .then(res => res.json() as Task)
47  .catch(error => {
48    this.handleError(error, 'Could not create task!')
49  });
50 }
51
52  update(task) {
53 const url = `${this.tasksUrl}/${task.id}?access_token=${localStorage.getItem('token')}`;
54 if (task['due_date'] && task['due_date']['formatted']) {
55  task['due_date'] = task['due_date']['formatted'];
56 }
57 return this.http.put(url, JSON.stringify(task), { headers: this.headers })
58  .toPromise()
59  .then(res => res.json() as Task)
60  .catch(error => {
61    this.handleError(error, 'Could not update task!')
62  });
63 }
```

---

### Here is the error in the terminal when I made changes to the code.

```
create(task): Promise<Task | void>
```

---

```
error terminal: 
ERROR in src/app/components/tasks/form.ts(62,26): error TS2345: Argument of type 'void | Task' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Task'.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Task'.
```

Tell me how to fix this error, I will be very grateful.

Comment: Looks like your catch section is not returning a <Task>. Can you tell what "this.handleError" is returning? My guess is it is returning void and hence the error. I can't be sure. Returning some <Task> from the catch should do it. Or there's always the reliable hack of "Promise<any>".

Comment: Yes, while I was waiting for an answer, I found the same answer to my question, you need to add any.
create (task): Promise <any | Task>.
Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to add Task if you add any : `Promise<any>` will do just fine. Anyway, I'm making an answer on why your error pops, and how to type your response correctly instead of `any`.

Comment: Well I actually can't make an answer since you didn't provide the code in error. As your error says, the error happens on line `62`, column `26`. Could you post your edited code and the line throwing the erorr ? (If of course, you want to type your response correctly instead of using any)

Comment: I updated the code, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently I was facing the same issue after I updated my typescript to version `2.7.2`

I fixed it by making the changes to `catch` block. My `errorHandler()` throws exception `Observable.throw` which is of type `ErrorObservable`

I simply chained the `Observable.throw` from my custom method which was calling `errorHandler()`. In your case it is `create()`

You could cimply do this

```
create(task): Promise<Task> {
    task['due_date'] = task['due_date']['formatted'];
    let body = JSON.stringify({task: task});
     const url = `${this.tasksUrl}?access_token=${localStorage.getItem('token')}`;
     return this.http.post(url, body, { headers: this.headers })
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => res.json() as Task)
      .catch(error => {
       Observable.throw(this.handleError(error, 'Could not create task!')); // chain Observable.throw
    });
}
```